# Write function for bsxfun with if/else

Tags: matlab, if-statement, bsxfun

In my code, I need to divide each values of a matrix by the values of another. I could use `A./B` but some elements in B are 0. I know that if B(i,j) = 0 so A(i,j) = 0 too and I want to have 0/0 = 0. So I wrote a function div and I use bsxfun but I don't have 0, I have NaN :

```
A = [1,0;1,1];
B = [1,0;1,2];
function n = div(a,b)
   if(b==0)
      n = 0;
   else
      n = a./b;
   end
end
C = bsxfun(@div,A,B);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just replace the unwanted values after?

```
C=A./B;
C(A==0 & B==0)=0;
```

You could do `C(isnan(C))=0;`, but this will replace all `NaN`, even the ones not created by `0/0`. If zeros always happen together then just `C(B==0)=0;` will do

Answer (score 1):

If you know your non-zero values in B are never smaller than a very small number eps (for example 1e-300), a simple trick is to add eps to B.  All non-zero values are unchanged, while all zero values become eps.   When dividing 0/eps you get the wished result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because `bsxfun` doesn't process the arrays element-wise. Consequently, your function doesn't get two scalars in. It is actually called only once. Your `if` statement does not work for non-scalar values of `b`.

Replacing `bsxfun` with [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) will call your function with scalar inputs, and will yield the expected result:

```
>> C = arrayfun(@div,A,B)
C =
    1.0000         0
    1.0000    0.5000
```

Nonetheless, either of the other two answers will be more efficient:

```
>> C = A./B;
>> C(B==0) = 0   % Ander's answer
C =
    1.0000         0
    1.0000    0.5000
```

or

```
C = A./(B+eps)   % user10259794's answer
C =
    1.0000         0
    1.0000    0.5000
```